# How to applications could check if a library is already installed in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to Android, this may be a noob question for some of you :).

Lets say that I have a library which could be used by multiple applications. In this case, apps would have to add the library as part of packaging process.

**First question:**
If multiple apps include the library, then there would be multiple copies of it right?

**second question**
If we need to avoid this, then, we need to have a mechanism where in apps would check if the library is already installed and then reuse the same. Is this possible?

Also I went through this: 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4161, is there any way to achieve this apart from the way mentioned here?

Answer (score 0):

if the library has an already existing activity (using third party apps) you can use this function:

```
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    List<ResolveInfo> list =
        packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but can we check this while an application is being deployed to Android device/Emulator?